# Customize form brought from Django forms.py

Tags: django

I got a form in Django but when I use `{{ form.as_p }}` it is not exactly what I am expecting.

How can I add a line break between the label and the input text area?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
label{
    margin-right: 5em; /* or larger if you need */
}
</style>
```

django template html file:

```
{% for field in form %}
<p>{{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

from [Customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)